# How to stop a jekyll local server

Tags: ruby, jekyll, webrick

I've just set up my first Jekyll project locally. I've got the server running, but I forgot to use the auto flag. So now I want to stop the server and restart using the flag. However, in my command line after I started the server I didn't get a new prompt, so I can't enter any new commands.
I'm not very used to the command line so I'd really appreciate knowing what I should do!
I'm using Mac OS X and terminal.app if that makes a difference!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can stop it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 18):

```
ps aux |grep jekyll |awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me since I want to stop jekyll using a grunt task, so CTRL + C wouldn't help.